# “CZML” extrude animation error

Tags: cesium

I wrote the code like this in Cesium 1.100 version.

the corresponding time and polygon are recognized, but the height is not recognized. how can i solve it?

```
  let czml = "";
  setInterval(function () { 
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/data",
      data: JSON, // Json
      success: function (res) {
        czml = res;
        const dataSource = new CzmlDataSource();

    function scaleProperty(property, scalingFactor) {
      // returns a property that scales another property by a constant factor.
      return new CallbackProperty(function (time, result) {
        result = property.getValue(time, result);
        result = result * scalingFactor;
        return result;
      }, property.isConstant);
    }

    function setExtrudedHeight(propertyName) {
      const customPropertyObject = dataSource.entities.getById(
        "water_extrudedheight"
      );
      const property = customPropertyObject.properties[propertyName];
      const colorado = dataSource.entities.getById("colorado");

      colorado.polygon.extrudedHeight = scaleProperty(property, 1);
    }

    // Custom properties can be used as the value of graphical properties:

    dataSource.load(czml);
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
    console.log(czml);
  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("not connection.");
  },
});
   }, 30000);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t include the “loadedPromise” function, and I didn’t create a function that executes “setExtrudedHeight”.